# Estimate the mean of a DataFrameGroupBy by only considering values in a percentile range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I need to estimate the mean of a pandas DataFrameGroupBy by only considering the values between a given percentile range.

For instance, given the snippet

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
a = np.matrix('1 1; 1 2; 1 4; 2 1; 2 2; 2 4')
data = pd.DataFrame(a)
groupby = data.groupby(0)
m1 = groupby.mean()
```

the result is

```
m1 =            1
      0          
      1  2.333333
      2  2.333333
```

However, if a percentile range is picked to exclude the maximum and minimum values the result should be

```
m1 =     1
      0          
      1  2
      2  2
```

How can I filter, for each group, the values between an **arbitrary** percentile range before estimating the mean? For instance, only considering the values between the 20th and 80th percentiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom function with either [`np.percentile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html) or [`pd.Series.quantile`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.quantile.html). The performance difference is marginal. The below example includes values only above the 20th and below the 80th percentile in calculating groupwise mean.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a = np.matrix('1 1; 1 2; 1 4; 2 1; 2 2; 2 4')
data = pd.DataFrame(a)

def jpp_np(df):
    def meaner(x, lowperc, highperc):
        low, high = np.percentile(x, [lowperc, highperc])
        return x[(x > low) & (x < high)].mean()
    return df.groupby(0)[1].apply(meaner, 20, 80).reset_index()

def jpp_pd(df):
    def meaner(x, lowperc, highperc):
        low, high = x.quantile([lowperc/100, highperc/100]).values
        return x[x.between(low, high, inclusive=False)].mean()
    return df.groupby(0)[1].apply(meaner, 20, 80).reset_index()

data = pd.concat([data]*10000)

assert np.array_equal(jpp_np(data), jpp_pd(data))

%timeit jpp_np(data)  # 11.2 ms per loop
%timeit jpp_pd(data)  # 12.5 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function to calculate this mean for a dataframe, then do use the apply method. Something like :

```
def mean_percent(df,per1,per2):
    #Write meaningful code here

data = pd.DataFrame(a)
groupby = data.groupby(0)
m1 = groupby.apply(lambda df: mean_percent(df,20,80))
```

This will calculate mean with value in 20-80 percentile range for each group.
If you need help writing the first function, feel free to ask in the comment, and i'll edit this answer.

Comment: Yep, implementing the `mean_percent` function will improve the self-containment of the answer :) Please also note that in pandas percentiles are included in [0, 1].

Answer (score 0):

try

```
data.sort_values(by=1).groupby(by=0).agg(['first','last']).mean()
```

OR

```
data.sort_values(by=1).groupby(by=0).agg(['min','max']).mean()
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to filter the dataframe before using groupby. You can sort the dataframe by the column of interest and then exclude the first and last rows.

```
data = data.sort_values(1).iloc[1:-1,:]
groupby = data.groupby(0)
m1 = groupby.mean()
```

Another side note: it's best practice to not use the same variable name as a common method such as 'groupby'. If you can change that to some other name, that would be highly recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`np.percentile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html) or [`np.quantile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.quantile.html#numpy.quantile) with `groupby`+`apply`:

```
a = np.matrix('1 1 2; 1 2 3; 1 4 4; 2 1 6; 2 2 8; 2 4 16;7 8 45;9 10 9;11 12 3')
df = pd.DataFrame(a,columns=['a','b','c'])
#drop column which is key for grouping
min_val,max_val = np.percentile(df.drop('a',1).values,[20,80],axis=0)
#alternative np.quantile(df.drop('a',1).values,[0.2,0.8],axis=0)
df1 = df.groupby('a').apply(lambda x: x[(x<max_val)&(x>min_val)].mean())

print(df1)
      b    c
a           
1   3.0  4.0
2   3.0  7.0
7   8.0  NaN
9   NaN  9.0
11  NaN  NaN
```